# How can I change/define default database of Mongodb in Spring-data?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, nosql

I have interfaces extends from MongoRepository. They are using default database of mongodb. I would like to define the database name for the classes.

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Customer, String> {
    ...
}
```

How can I define it?

Comment: What do you mean by database name for classes?
Do you mean to say `Document` name (table name) for classes?

Comment: @SanjayRawat lets say in my mongod i have more than one database. I would like use first one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need to define respective mongobd properties in `application.properties` file or if you want to yml syntax then define props in `application.yml`. Under `src/main/resources`, `application.properties` should be there already.

`application.properties` :

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=<hostname> 
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017 
spring.data.mongodb.database=<dbname>
spring.data.mongodb.username=<usernamr>
spring.data.mongodb.password=******
```

Or

`application.yml` :

```
spring: 
    data: 
        mongodb: 
            host: <hostname> 
            port: 27017 
            database: <dbname>
            username: <usernamr>
            password: ******
```

Comment: Thank you. Can we use multiple databases?

Comment: I guess so. Found this http://smasue.github.io/spring-yml-datasources for JPA, can be applied to Mongo with manual configuration.

Comment: @Furkan have you found a way to use multiple connections with the default configuration?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Spring Boot, the following steps might help you.

- Define the following properties in application.properties or yml descriptor. note the properties should start with spring.data.mongodb. If you are using Mongo 3.x java driver, spring.data.mongodb.uri should be used to provide uri configurations.

  ```
  spring.profiles: myprofile
  spring.data.mongodb.uri: mongodb://user:passwd@url:port/dbname 
  spring.data.mongodb.database:myDB
  ```
- Write SpringMongoConfiguration.

  ```
  @Configuration
  @EnableMongoRepostories("path.to.your.repository")
  public class SpringMongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

  @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
  private String mongoDB;

  @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
  private String mongoURI;

  @Override
  protected String getDatabaseName() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return mongoDB;
  }

  @Override
  public MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext()
          throws ClassNotFoundException {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return super.mongoMappingContext();
  }

  @Override
  @Bean
  public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
      return new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(myURI));
  }
   }
  ```
- Build your project and run your spring boot app

  java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=myprofile your-app.jar

Answer (score -1):

If you are using context XML add the following in your XML and define the database configurations.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <mongo:mongo-client credentials="user:password@database" />

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo"/>
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="myDBName"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Alternatively, Define a class by extending AbstractMongoConfiguration and override the getDatabaseName().

```
@Configuration
public class SpringDBConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration
{ 

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "testdatabase";
    }
    ......         
}
```

Comment: There is no XML in Spring Boot.

Comment: The question has a `spring-boot` tag, so you can't suggest to configure a XML!