# Mongodb + SpringBoot REST API + Docker Compose not working

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to use docker-compose to run my Springboot REST API, which uses Mongo as a database, but I'm receiving the following error. Could someone please assist me in resolving this?

When my spring-boot application tries to connect to MongoDB via the Docker container, it gives me problems. Spring-boot appears to be unable to connect to MongoDB on port 27017.

Below is the part of the code and exception.

**DockerFile**

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

**Docker-Compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:

      sprintpoker-springboot-container:
            image: sprintpoker-springboot
            build:
                  context: ./
                  dockerfile: Dockerfile
            volumes:
                  - /data/sprintpoker-springboot-container
            ports:
                  - 8080:8080
            depends_on:
                  - mongo

      mongo:
            image: mongo
            container_name: mongodb
            ports:
                  - 27017:27017
            volumes:
                  - data:/data
            environment:
                  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: rootuser
                  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpass

      mongo-express:
            image: mongo-express
            restart: always
            ports:
                  - 8081:8081
            environment:
                  ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: rootuser
                  ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: rootpass
                  ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongo
volumes:
      data: {}
networks:
      default:
            name: mongodb_network
```

**Command I am use to run docker:**

```
docker-compose up -d --build --force-recreate --renew-anon-volumes
```

**Exception on spring-boot docker container:**

```
2021-08-16 03:16:02.453 INFO 1 --- [ main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}

2021-08-16 03:16:02.545 INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017


com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket

at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar!/:na]

at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:143) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar!/:na]

at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar!/:na]

at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar!/:na]

at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]

at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar!/:na]

at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar!/:na]

at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar!/:na]

... 4 common frames omitted
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.username=rootuser
spring.data.mongodb.password=rootpass
spring.data.mongodb.database=sprint
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=true
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you also share the spring boot snippet, where you configured spring boot to connect to mongodb ?

Comment: According to the error, spring is using localhost:27017, therefore trying to on connect to itself, not `mongo:27017`, the other container

Comment: @RafafTahsin I am using JPA, so did you want me to share application.properties file?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I didn't understand, which line you talking about.

Comment: He means `2021-08-16 03:16:02.545 INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017`. The address should be `mongo:27017`.

Comment: Regardless, you should still [edit] your question to include the Spring properties file(s)

Comment: @OneCricketeer added the properties file content.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to resolve the issue Thanks to @OneCricketeer and @Michał Krzywański ([Mongodb connection error though docker in springboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62353247/mongodb-connection-error-though-docker-in-springboot?rq=1)).

Solution:
Added below line in docker-compose file:

```
environment:
      - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_.HOST=mongo

 expose:
                  - 27017
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here

`2021-08-16 03:16:02.545 INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017`

The Spring app container isn't running anything on port 27017, let alone a MongoDB server.

Change

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
```

to

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=mongo
```

Comment: I tried this to do, still getting same error:

```
2021-08-18 04:51:33.254 INFO 1 --- [ main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}

2021-08-18 04:51:33.366 INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar!/:na]
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34373673/2308683

Answer (score 0):

1. Application.yaml / properties file

> ```
> spring:
>         data:
>           mongodb:
>             database: test
>             host: mymongodb
>             port: 27017
> ```

```
        spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
        spring.data.mongodb.host=<mongo-image-name>
        spring.data.mongodb.database=<any-database-name>
```

2. Create mongo image :-

> docker pull mongo:latest

3. Stop Local Mongo Service as it runs on the same port
4. Run docker image :-

> docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --name mymongodb mongo:latest --mymongodb
> is the container name and will be the host name in yaml or properties
> file

5. DockerFile Example :-

> ```
> FROM openjdk:11
>       ADD target/springboot-mongo-docker.jar app.jar
>       EXPOSE 8080
>       ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
> ```

6. Build the jar :- mvn clean install
7. Build Docker Image :- docker build -t springboot-mongodb:1.0 .
8. Run The Linked Container as follows :-

> docker run -p 8080:8080 --name springboot-mongodb --link
> mymongodb:mongo -d springboot-mongodb:1.0

9. docker-compose.yml :-

> docker-compose up

```
> version: "3"      
     services:       mymongodb:
>          image: mongo:latest
>          container_name: "mymongodb"
>          ports:
>            - 27017:27017       springboot-mongodb:
>          image: springboot-mongodb:1.0
>          container_name: springboot-mongodb
>          ports:
>            - 8080:8080
>          links:
>            - mymongodb
```